# How can I save a Google Pixel 4a stuck during boot?

Tags: boot-loop, boot, google-pixel-4a

I got a Google Pixel 4a that is stuck during boot without obvious reason (maybe it did an automatic update and restart during the night). Whenever I start the phone, it only shows the "Google lettering" but won't continue to boot.

I can access fastboot (vol- + power button). That way, I have also access to the phone via cmd console on my computer. Still, when I try to access recovery mode, it will also get stuck when it shows the Google lettering. Also, a wipe or factory reset is not possible via power button + vol+ as I cannot access recovery mode. Resetting the phone via https://flash.android.com is also not possible with the error message:

> Device Unlock Disabled
>
> For security reasons, you need to enable "OEM unlocking" in order to flash your device. See the device preparation instructions for more information.

So what other options do I have to get the phone back running?

Comment: Pixel4a does no longer receive updates. Last update was released 2023-08-05.

Answer (score 0):

If fastboot mode is accessible, please use the command `fastboot -w` to trigger a factory reset on the device.

Comment: Already tried. Only gave me an error. Maybe because it is locked?